# Polymorphic association not showing correctly on rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've just finished adding some notifications functionality into my app. However, when I check a notification on rails admin, it's not detecting the associated polymorphic object.
I only use rails admin in development.. so if this a rails admin bug, then I'm happy to leave it. However (and most likely) if i've done something wrong, I need to fix it.

I should mention - **this is working in the database and works everywhere on site, except rails admin**

My models

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notified, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :object, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  scope :not_seen, -> { where(seen: false) }
  scope :not_clicked, -> { where(clicked: false) }


  def self.send_notifications(user, message, object, subscribers, mailer = nil, mailer_object = nil)
    subscribers.uniq.each do |subscriber|
      self.create({user: user, message: message, notified: subscriber, object: object}) unless subscriber.get_user_id == user.id
      UserMailer.send(mailer, subscriber, mailer_object).deliver unless mailer.nil? || subscriber.get_user_id == user.id
    end
  end

end
```

All_Models_that_can_be_notified_about.rb

```
class .... < ActiveRecord::Base
..
  has_many :notifications, as: :object
..
end
```

Here's the line that creates the notification

```
self.create({user: user, message: message, notified: subscriber, object: object}) unless subscriber.get_user_id == user.id
```

Here's what it looks like on the console:

```
<Notification id: 7, user_id: 1, message: " has left a comment on ", notified_id: 2, notified_type: "Programme", created_at: "2015-10-09 12:51:07", updated_at: "2015-10-09 12:51:07", seen: true, clicked: true, object_id: 54, object_type: "Applicant">
```

As you can see from above, the `object_id` and `object_type` are populated (54, Applicant)

But in Rails admin, I get this:

[image]

It's detecting the model is Applicant, but it's not seeing the ID

Any thoughts?

Comment: `object` is an unfortunate choice of name, since `#object_id` is already defined as a method on Ruby objects. I don't know if that's the source of the problem, but you might consider changing `object` to something else to avoid potential issues.

Comment: Thank you! That was the source of the problem. If you could make this an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I suspected as much. Name collisions can be very hard to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have discovered one of the rare and bedeviling name collisions from which Rails suffers. An all-too-brief mention of this is made in the [Rails Guide to ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#avoiding-name-collisions)

> **3.2 Avoiding Name Collisions**
>
> You are not free to use just any name for your associations. Because
>   creating an association adds a method with that name to the model, it
>   is a bad idea to give an association a name that is already used for
>   an instance method of ActiveRecord::Base. The association method would
>   override the base method and break things. For instance, attributes or
>   connection are bad names for associations.

`object_id` is defined by Ruby on all objects. It returns the numeric ID that identifies the object, and unfortunately (as you discovered), it is possible to override this method with another one, which is what happens when you create an association named `object`.

An `object_id` attribute is automatically added when a model is instantiated from a table with a column named `object_id`. At some point the `object_id` method is being called to identify an object, but the value returned is coming from the attribute. Thus the problem.

Renaming the association is probably the only way around this.